# How can I parse this Date in  Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to parse a date into my format like `02:09 AM 25/09/2012` but I can't. I used this code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, DD yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

//September, 25 2012 02:09:42 +0000
Date date = sdf1.parse(String.valueOf(PUNCH_TIME)); 

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH':'mm a 'on' DD'/'MMMM'/'yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
String timeformat=sdf2.format(date);
txtHomePunchStatus.setText("You have Punched In at "+timeformat);
```

and I got `You have punched IN at 7:52 AM on 25/01/2012`.

Comment: can you try with hh:mm a? small hh not HH.

Comment: i tried and got all the correct values but not getting the "MM" value correctly

Comment: Can you please give an example of the output you expect?

Comment: i don't understand the problem

Comment: i am getting this from webservice September, 25 2012 02:09:42 +0000

and want to parse in 02:09 AM 25/09/2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have issues with the time zone. The input string `September, 25 2012 02:09:42 +0000` is a timestamp in UTC (offset `+0000`). When you format your date in the desired format, you're not specifying a time zone, so the `SimpleDateFormat` object is going to show your date in your local time zone, which is probably not UTC.

What you can do is set the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat` object that you use to format the date. For example:

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = df1.parse(PUNCH_TIME);

DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a 'on' dd/MM/yyyy");
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String result = df2.format(date);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Note**: You must use `dd` and not `DD` for the days; `DD` means day number of the year, `dd` means day number in the month (see the API documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`).

p.s.: Your usage of the words "parse" and "format" is confusing. **Parsing** means: converting from a string to a `Date` object, and **formatting** means the opposite: converting from a `Date` object to a string.

Answer (score 0):

First off you have a double declaration of `sdf2`. Then, you need to use `hh` and `mm` for hours and minutes. Read the documentation: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Like in this example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, DD yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

    //September, 25 2012 02:09:42 +0000
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf1.parse(String.valueOf(PUNCH_TIME));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a 'on' DD/MM/yyyy");

    String timeformat=sdf2.format(date);
```

Comment: @SmitPatel remember that months are 0-based. So 0 = January, 1 = February, ..., 8 = September, 9 = October, ..., 11 = December. If the month is September, expect 8, not 9.

Comment: @SmitPatel with the above code I get this output: `02:09 AM on 25/09/2012`. Maybe your `PUNCH_TIME` is not the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(
    "September, 25 2012 02:09:42 +0000" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM, d uuuu HH:mm:ss Z" , Locale.US ) 
).format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a 'on' dd/MM/uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
```

> 02:09 AM on 25/09/2012

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers are now outmoded, using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. The old classes are supplanted by the java.time classes. For earlier Android, see the last bullets below.

## java.time

Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.

```
String input = "September, 25 2012 02:09:42 +0000" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM, d uuuu HH:mm:ss Z" , Locale.US ) ;  // Specify a locale for the human language by which to parse the name of the month.
```

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime` given that your input specifies an offset-from-UTC but not a full time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

> odt.toString(): 2012-09-25T02:09:42Z

To generate a string in an alternate format, define a `DateTimeFormatter` with a custom formatting pattern. Pay attention to the uppercase/lowercase of your formatting code characters, and study closely [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Note that colons, spaces, and slashes are known by the formatter, so no need to escape those characters with the single-quote marks.

```
DateTimeFormatter fOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a 'on' dd/MM/uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = odt.format( fOutput) ;
```

> 02:09 AM on 25/09/2012

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).